# Win 7 laptop taking a long time to log on when off the domain

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, login

I've clicked through on a few forums but unable to find a suggestion for this issue. I have a user with a HP laptop which will boot perfectly fine whilst connected to the network but at home it will take 4 minutes to log on.

Some suggestions I have had is that its looking for the DNS server of the domain. Another was that it was suggested it was a roaming profile (it isn't).

So hoping someone has encountered Windows 7 acting like this and has some suggestions. The other users on this domain don't have the issue and its a mix of XP and Win 7 client PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your logon scripts. Are they trying to access a network resource which isn't available when the machine in not connected to the domain network?

I've seen a similar problem during boot, which turned out to be a computer start up script trying to access a network resource that wasn't available offline.

Another option is to enable userenv logging to determine exactly what causes the delay.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, this user is a consultant who has a domain profile> i just removed his login script and create a manual login script for him to run. Seems to boot in quicker, this is with the wi-fi adapter turned off to emulate being at home.. then again it might just be that because the wi-fi is off its quicker..

Answer (score 0):

Bryan is on the right track, in that the most common problem is the machine trying to connect to a network resource that is unavailable when off the network. However, it normally won't be due to a logon script because those normally run from the server, not the client, in a domain environment and therefore won't come into play when off the network.

Check for things like drive mappings and perhaps even network printer connections. In each case where I've encountered the problem you describe there is a mapped drive that was mapped as persistent, either manually or via a script. Sometimes this is far from obvious and may require a search of the registry to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You might suggest the user turn off their WiFi card (most notebooks have hardware flip swithces to turn it off) during boot up, and turn it on once logged in.

Our domain notebooks use a Group Policy configured wireless netowrk on our campus which pre-authenticates the machine before login.  This causes 30-45min boots off site unless the WiFi is turned off.

Answer (score -1):

try to disable the startup items or services and reboot.

If - the station boots / you log on - quickly then you can perform items activation one by one 
and each time reboot the station to see witch service is causing the pc to hang when offline.

UpToYou...